# Using WordPress portfolios

Tags: wordpress

So I'm making a Wordpress site for a handmade wooden furniture business and I am kind of new to Wordpress. They want a place to showcase their work but they are not at the stage to have an online shop. I am currently using portfolios to display their work.

Should it be one item per portfolio and organise them with categories, or multiple items per portfolio and give the portfolio a category name (ex. "Tables")?

The items are just pictures and there is not much to say about each of them.  Also if there are any better practices than using portfolios for this type of thing let me know.
thanks

Answer (score -1):

you can find and choose from many of the plugins the Portfolio plugin. They have a many settings and also categories. After install it will a post named Portfolio in your admin-panel